# Installed Views Module but It did not appeared in Structure

Tags: views, nodes

I installed a fresh Drupal 7.22 on my localhost and installed Ctools and Views modules.

When i go to **Structure** i dint find **Views** link

I also cleared all cache but still same problem.

This is not my first Drupal experience, I created many views.

Here are the screen shots.

[image: Modules List]
[image: Structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable **Views UI** in order for it to show up under Admin -> Structure.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still not seeing after enabling Views-UI and IF YOU USING ADMIN MENU module to generate Admin Menus, You have to clear cache.

To do that,

Home Icon -> Flush all caches -> Administration menu
Home Icon -> Flush all caches -> Menu

Comment: This is not an answer to the question actually asked here. Also, questions that can be answered with a mere cache clear are not even on-topic here.

Comment: That was my experience. Because I have enabled View and View-UI and it didnt appear on the Structure block.